# How to use a variable declared in super method of parent Class inside same metod of inherited Class

Tags: javascript

For example we got class A :

```
class A {
    methodA() {
        let x = 1
        //do something with x
        return x
    }
}
```

and its child class B with same method :

```
class B extends A {
    metodA() {
        super.metodA() 
        //how to get a var x here ?
        //dosomething with x
    }
}
```

of course variable x is undefined inside method .

But i need it . What is best way to get it inside method of class B ?

Comment: you cannot get to that variable as it's currently declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are returning the variable from `methodA()` you can just receive it with the caller:

```js
class A {
    methodA() {
        let x = "Some Value from A"
        //do something with x
        return x
    }
}

class B extends A {
    methodA() {
        let x = super.methodA() 
        console.log("x:", x)
        //how to get a var x here ?
        //dosomething with x
    }
}

let b = new B
b.methodA()
```

An alternative would be to set the variable as an instance variable rather than declaring it with `var` which will be scoped to the function. Then you can retrieve it with `this.x`:

```js
class A {
    methodA() {
         this.x = "Some Value"
        //do something with this.x
    }
}

class B extends A {
    methodA() {
        super.methodA() 
        console.log("x:", this.x)
    }
}

let b = new B
b.methodA()
```

Comment: Thank you . What if i didn't return it ? Is it still accessible ?

Comment: @Vitozz_RDX the variable is scoped to the function, so as is, no. But see edit for an option.